# How can i display event (row) count in Splunk dashboard panel

Tags: splunk

I have created a dashboard panel for one of my SPL query which gives me list of results. For that i want to display the count of entries on the top of that panel.

I tried to set the token in the source XML but it didn't work.

````
  <label>mytestdashboard</label>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>TotalEvents $countResult$</title>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <progress>
            <set token="countResult">$job.Count$</set>
          </progress>
          <query>host="homework"</query>
          <earliest>0</earliest>
          <latest></latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>
        <option name="charting.drilldown">none</option>
        <option name="refresh.display">preview</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
  </row>
</dashboard>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value $job.Count$ to $job.resultCount$ because the count can be set using job.resultCount.

Try this.

```
<progress>
            <set token="countResult">$job.resultCount$</set>
</progress>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can I use the same token name for different panels

Comment: @jessyWilliams - once you're created a token, you can use it anywhere on the same dashboard.